# Const Methods that Return References

Tags: c++, class, methods, constants

```
class Foo
{
    int Bar;

    public:

    int& GetBar() const
    {
        return Bar;
    }
}
```

Is it okay that `GetBar` is a `const` method?  It's not actually changing anything, but it's providing the "outside world" with a means of changing it.

Comment: I think you've already answered your question. Additionally in example Bar is already public.

Comment: `&Bar` has type `const int*`, not `int&`. You compiler should be telling you that this is not OK.

Comment: Have you tried compiling? What did the compiler tell you?

Comment: @Charles : this comment and the comment on my post make sense. So I deleted my post. thanks. :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, this is what you probably meant:

```
class Foo
{
    int Bar;

    public:

    int& GetBar() const
    {
        return Bar; // Removed the ampersand, because a reference is returned, not an address
    }
}
```

And no, this is not legal. When tagging a method with `const`, not only are you promising you won't touch any of the internal state of the object, you also promise that you will not return anything that can be used to change the state of the object. A non-const reference may be used to modify the value of Bar outside the scope of `GetBar()`, hence you are implying that you cannot hold the promise.

You must either change the method to being non-const, return a const reference, or make `Bar` exempt of the promise by marking it as `mutable`. E.g.: `mutable int Bar;` The `mutable` keyword tells the compiler that the logical constness of the object does not depend on the state of `Bar`. Then you are allowed to do whatever you please with it.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, since you cant do the following assignment:
`const int x; int &y = x;`

What you can do though is `const int x; const int &y = x;`

And of course there is no problem in overloading the method and creating both const and non-const variants.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to return `Bar`, not `&Bar`. Anyway, I dropped this code in Comeau:

```
class Foo
{
    int Bar;

    public:

    int& GetBar() const
    {
        return &Bar;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Foo x;
  int y = x.GetBar();
  y = 5;
  return 0;
}
```

And got the error:

```
line 9: error: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type
          "int &" to initializer of type "const int"
          return Bar;
                 ^
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to return a reference you don't need to use the ampersand operator on the referenced object; it is needed if you want to get a *pointer* to it. So, I assume you wanted to write `return Bar;`.

Then, no, you can't do that; in a `const` method you have a `const` `this` pointer (in your case it would be a `const Foo *`), which means that any reference you can get to its fields<sup>1</sup> will be a `const` reference, since you're accessing them through a "`const` path".

Thus, if you try to do what you did in that code you'll get a compilation error, since you'd be trying to initialize an `int &` (the return value of your method) with a `const int &` (the reference you get from `Bar`), which obviously is forbidden.

g++ actually says:

```
testconstref.cpp: In member function ‘int& Foo::GetBar() const’:
testconstref.cpp:9: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from a temporary of type ‘const int*’
```

which is what I just said. `:)`

If, instead, you return a `const` reference to a class field from a `const` method you'll have no problem.

---

1. Excluding fields marked as `mutable`, which tells to the compiler that such fields are modifiable even from `const` methods; this exception has been introduced to allow `const` methods to change the "real" state of the object in cases when this do not alter its "logical" state; this can be useful to implement lazy evaluation, reference counting, ...

Answer (score 1):

The members of your class are considered const when you are in a const method. So although `Bar` is `int` within your class and not `const int`, in the context of `GetBar() const` it is "const int". Therefore returning it as a non-const reference or pointer is just as illegal as doing:

`const int y = 57;
 int& z = y;`

This breaks const-correctness even though the 2nd line has not actually changed anything (yet) in y.

Note incidentally that if your class has pointer members the only thing that is const is the pointers themselves and not what they point to. (Often referred to as "shallow" constness)

Thus this would be legal:

```
class A
{
  Foo * foo;

  public:
    Foo * getFoo() const // legal. does not have to return const Foo *
    {
       return foo;
    }
};
```

Note that in your original code you would be allowed to return `Bar` by non-const reference if it were `mutable`, because those members are not bound by the constness of member functions.

Answer (score 0):

`const` modifier to a member function doesn't allow to change the object's state with in it's scope. Compiler just checks whether this function is modifying the state of the object or not in its scope. Taking another example -

```
class foo
{
    int num ;
    public :
       foo( int anum )
       {
           anum = 10;
       }
       int getNum()
       {
           return num;
       }
 };

 foo obj;
 int& myNum = obj.getNum() ; // myNum is just an alias to the private class variable num
 myNum = 40; // Actually changes the content of the private variable.
```

So, compiler just checks access specifiers ( i.e., whether this variable is accessible or not in this scope) but not about the private/public/protected variable's memory location if returned to some other variable.